# prepare() not working

Tags: sql, wpdb

When I do this:

```
$transients = $wpdb->get_col(
    "
    SELECT     option_name
    FROM       $wpdb->options
    WHERE      option_name
    LIKE       '_transient_wb_tt_%'
    "
);
```

It works fine, but when I use prepare like so:

```
$transients = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT     option_name
    FROM       %s
    WHERE      option_name
    LIKE       '_transient_wb_tt_%'
    ",
    $wpdb->options
) );
```

It doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why are you using prepare here?

Comment: I was thinking as good practice to prepare everything but after looking over the examples maybe it's just silly?

Comment: Prepare is used to escape and sanitize user input which is not really your case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @bainternet. You don't need `$wpdb->prepare`. There isn't any user supplied content.

The answer to the question is that to get a wildcard `%` to pass through `prepare` you need to double it in your code.

```
LIKE  '_transient_wb_tt_%%'
```

Try that or this if you want a good look at the generated query:

```
var_dump($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT     option_name
    FROM       %s
    WHERE      option_name
    LIKE       '_transient_wb_tt_%%'
    ",
    'abc')); 
die;
```

Other than being unnecessary, using `$wpdb->prepare` like this won't work. The attempt to use `prepare` to swap in the tablename will result in a tablename with quotes around it. That is invalid SQL. The query should be simple:

```
SELECT     option_name
FROM       {$wpdb->options}
WHERE      option_name
LIKE       '_transient_wb_tt_%%'
```

Comment: I just spotted this and tried it before but it is now spitting out - WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_options' WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_wb_tt_%'' at line 2]
SELECT option_name FROM 'wp_options' WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_wb_tt_%'

Comment: var_dump output - string(133) " SELECT option_name FROM 'wp_options' WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_wb_tt_%' " Array ( )

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around the tablename. I just noticed that you were using `prepare` to swap in the the tablename. Don't do that. It won't work. `$wpdb->options` is a safe value. Just write it into the query directly.

Answer (score 1):

From [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/)

```
$wild = '%';
$find = 'only 43% of planets';
$like = $wild . $wpdb->esc_like( $find ) . $wild;
$sql  = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_content LIKE %s", $like );
```

The essential part is -> "$like = $wild . $wpdb->esc_like( $find ) . $wild;"