# Check if values exists DB

Tags: php, functions, customization, database, query

I am getting nutts with this one.

I want to check if the email introduced in the form already exists in the database before creating a new record.
But for some reason the email is empty at search time but when gets into the database gets it correct value from the form.

The PHP @ 'functions.php':

```
function qsmp_register($name, $mail, $password, $terms, $newsletter) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'qsmp_mails';

    $query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE email = %s ', $table_name, $mail );

    $cEMAIL = $wpdb->get_var( $query );

    if ($cEMAIL < 1)
    {
```

The HTML:

```
<form class="reg-page" name="register" action="<?php qsmp_register( $_POST['qsmp_name'],
                                                                                $_POST['qsmp_email3'],
                                                                                $_POST['qsmp_password3'],
                                                                                $_POST['qsmp_terms'],
                                                                                $_POST['qsmp_newsletter']) ?>" method="post">
                <div class="reg-header">
                    <h2>Register a new account</h2>                  
                </div>
```

Comment: Does your check raw as raw SQL query directly on database?

Comment: well if I create a new variable like $mail2 = "some_email_already_in_db" it works... the problem here is the variable $mail that is empty at the time of the query...how this is possible?

Comment: You cannot use `prepare` to replace table names-- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83010/21376

Comment: this is an example from wordpress website:<?php
// set the meta_key to the appropriate custom field meta key
$meta_key = 'miles';
$allmiles = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
 "
  SELECT sum(meta_value) 
  FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
  WHERE meta_key = %s
 ", 
 $meta_key
) );
echo "<p>Total miles is {$allmiles}</p>";
?>  And this is working.